# Maven3 plugin repository

Tags: maven, soap, maven-2, maven-3

Can anyone tell me why my Maven3 is not able to download the jetty plugin from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/6.1.20/jetty-maven-plugin-6.1.20.pom ?

I have included the eviware and the jetty plugin also to automate the SOAP UI test cases.

It will be helpful if anyone can suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? How does your pom look like?

Comment: It has been renamed to jetty-maven-plugin, the maven-jetty-plugin 6.1.20 is under [/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/).

Comment: I am unable to open this link.. /maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/ ...It says Server Notfound.

Comment: Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/6.1.10/jetty-maven-plugin-6.1.10.pom
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE[ERROR] Plugin org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:6.1.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:jar:6.1.10: Could not transfer artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:pom:6.1.10 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: If you get unknown host you have a network problem. Proxy?

Comment: Can you please help me in setting the proxy setting?Thanks in advance..

Comment: Google was too simple...http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: Even after implementing that I have no luck.I have adde below things.<proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
<!--      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</hoSt> -->
      <port>8080</port>
      <!--<username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.somewhere.com</nonProxyHosts>-->
    </proxy>

Comment: why `<host>` is commented?

Comment: If you want to use version 6.X.XX, in your pom.xml, set plugin's artifactId to `<artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>`. If you want to use version 7.X.XX, in your pom.xml, set plugin's artifactId to `<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>`.

Comment: I was unaware Vinay which  host name should i use.So I commented it

Comment: Yorkw, It is not the issue of artifact ..I am unable to connect to maven repofrom local or through from broswer.I mean i am unable to connect to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.20/maven-jetty-plugin-6.1.20.pom

Answer (score 0):

you can change the layout of the repository, some thing like this

```
<repository>
<id>CentralRepository</id>
<name>CentralRepository</name>
<url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/</url>
<layout>version</layout>
<releases>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</releases>
<snapshots>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</snapshots>
</repository>
```